# EC2: When do userdata scripts run compared to rc.d bootup scripts?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Do the userdata scripts run before or after the ones set up to run on every boot? Is there a way to change the priority?

Answer (score 3):

Userdata scripts are run from `/etc/init.d/cloud-init-user-scripts` which has both a start-up and shutdown priority of "99", meaning its the last one run.  There is no way to change it, short of burning a new AMI with a new priority specified in the init.d script.